Do we have shared code between angular packages in actual angular repo?
I am looking a way where i am thinking to contribute to https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages but I am not sure for things.
Q1: Does there exist a shared package that can be used by some other angular/* packages folder?
Q2: Will the Angular team accept improvements where shared constants are repeatedly added inline in different directories but can be defined once and used in multiple packages?
